# How to make always active session for postgresql?

Tags: django, linux, postgresql, debian

Previously, I had a django application/database on the same server.
Now I have made one server with application, one server with database(Debian 11; Postgresql 12.9 (Install via Homebrew))

Problem: after a few hours there are problems with connecting to the database...

postgres log:

```
2022-01-24 23:27:00.315 UTC [9982] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2022-01-24 23:27:00.323 UTC [9982] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 9996) exited with exit code 1
2022-01-24 23:27:00.324 UTC [9991] LOG:  shutting down
2022-01-24 23:27:00.344 UTC [9982] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

/var/log/syslog:

```
Jan 24 23:27:00 d systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Jan 24 23:27:00 d systemd[8909]: Stopped target Main User Target.
Jan 24 23:27:00 d systemd[8909]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Jan 24 23:27:00 d systemd[8909]: Stopping Homebrew generated unit for postgresql@12...
Jan 24 23:27:00 d systemd[8909]: dbus.service: Succeeded.
Jan 24 23:27:00 d systemd[8909]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Jan 24 23:27:00 d systemd[8909]: homebrew.postgresql@12.service: Succeeded.
Jan 24 23:27:00 d systemd[8909]: Stopped Homebrew generated unit for postgresql@12.
Jan 24 23:27:00 d systemd[8909]: homebrew.postgresql@12.service: Consumed 1min 22.614s CPU time.
Jan 24 23:27:00 d systemd[8909]: Removed slice app-homebrew.postgresql.slice.
Jan 24 23:27:00 d systemd[8909]: app-homebrew.postgresql.slice: Consumed 1min 22.614s CPU time.
Jan 24 23:27:00 d systemd[8909]: Stopped target Basic System.
...
```

I connect to server via terminal from my local computer. I see only my sessions(loginctl list-sessions), if I kill it, then postgresql will fall again.

I need to  create a user that will be permanently active? How to do it right?

Comment: where does the database server is hosted ? is it an AWS instance ? is it a Spot instance ?

Comment: I would use Debian's own package manager (apt) to install PostgreSQL, and also check that it is an always running service

Comment: and why are you usin homebrew for a production server ? use the officile PostgreSQL debian packages: https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/debian/how-to-install-postgresql-on-debian-11-debian-10.html

Comment: @mshabou cloud server at hetzner.com

Comment: Is it better not to use homebrew in production? Ok, i will try to install postgresql from Debian's own package.

Comment: Your server got shot down. You cannot maintain a database connection in that case. Perhaps you should add more description about the setup and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't know what it was, but installing officile PostgreSQL debian packages helped. Postgresql active 1 day 1 hour. Thanx mshabou and trajekolus.